# Clean OnBeforeExit Popup (Facebook style?)

Tags: javascript, facebook, jquery-ui, jquery

when you're about to leave a FB page after ALMOST writing characters into a wall-post field, how does FB prompt a clean looking dialogue instead of a spammy looking js alert box?

Eg:
[image: Facebook on exit alert]

I'd like to implement something similar on my site when people are about to leave after beginning a form.

Thanks!

Comment: debug it! take a look at your debugger and trace the events fired.

Answer (score 1):

Set a global javascript variable with the editting status.

Set to true when the user is interacting with your form.
Set to false when the form is "reset" or "cancelled".

On the document's onunload event (http://www.zachleat.com/web/dont-let-the-door-hit-you-onunload-and-onbeforeunload/ and http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_The_Back_Button_With_Javascript), check the editting status and popup a message with two buttons.  If the user clicks Leave, return true in the onunload event.  If the user clicks Stay, return false to the onunload event.

Happy coding!